# How do I reassign conflicting IRQs?

Tags: windows-xp, interrupts

My computer has several conflicting IRQs, which I think may be causing some instability in the system.  I would like to reassign the conflicting IRQs to unused slots.  However, when I open a device's properties from Device Manager and go to its Resources tab, the option to "Use automatic settings" is disabled/grayed out.  Is there another way that I can change the IRQ assignments?  I am using Windows XP-64 Pro.  Thanks.

Comment: Here's a link to a screen capture of my Device Manager showing the current IRQ assignments: http://attachments.techguy.org/attachments/162339d1262368313/device-manager-irqs.jpg

Comment: About 25% to 75% of the time when I boot my computer, it blue-screens (http://attachments.techguy.org/attachments/162503d1262669945/img_0672-cropped.jpg). There are also other times when the computer seems to lockup, sometime after booting, for no apparent reason, which, just as hunch, I think is related to the first issue. The Event Viewer shows only DCOM errors, which, as I understand, doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the option to "Use automatic settings"
>   is disabled/grayed out.

This is disabled because Windows automatically and successfully installed the device **without conflict**.

*can you be more specific? which device? a screen shot of the device manager maybe?*

Comment: Hello Molly.  Yes, the Device Manager does report no conflicts, but viewing the IRQ assignments tells a different story.  Here's a link to a screen capture of the Device Manager: http://attachments.techguy.org/attachments/162339d1262368313/device-manager-irqs.jpg

Comment: shared IRQs are not uncommon and do not necessarily constitute a conflict. if there was a conflict between devices, you'd see a red X on one of the devices sharing the IRQ with another.

Comment: About 25% to 75% of the time when I boot my computer, it blue-screens (http://attachments.techguy.org/attachments/162503d1262669945/img_0672-cropped.jpg). There are also other times when the computer seems to lockup, sometime after booting, for no apparent reason, which, just as hunch, I think is related to the first issue. The Event Viewer shows only DCOM errors, which, as I understand, doesn't mean anything.